# Why doesn't Aiden already know about the satellite?

Tags: plot-explanation, argylle

In "Argylle", we learn that writer Elly Conway

> is actually a brainwashed super spy, and the spy stories she writes are actually her previous missions. She is the real life Agent Argylle, and Aiden is the real life Agent Wyatt. In the film, when she imagines Argylle and Wyatt doing something, she's actually remembering something she had done earlier with Aiden.

When Aiden and Elly visit the Albert Memorial, where the hacker "Argylle" was supposed to meet never shows, Aiden prompts her through the process of "writing the next chapter" -- which is basically

> getting her to actually remember what happened. Elly imagines Argylle meeting with Wyatt in a car, the two of them discovering an encrypted chip in the burner phone, tracking down the hacker's satellite, and figuring out the location of the hacker's flat.

The two then go to the flat and the plot progresses. But if "Argylle" and "Wyatt" had figured out the stuff about the encrypted chip, why did Aiden (the real life "Wyatt") need to go through this memory exercise with Elly? He would have already known about the satellite, flat, etc., because he had been part of the original discovery.